# Sleeping in Spring Boot thread while running a new thread with ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, spring-boot, executorservice

I have implemented API REST using Spring Boot used for some user interfaces showing information about devices connected to the network. The API REST use in turn a DAO class that gather the information by sending a raw Ethernet frame and collecting the devices responses.

So I am using Pcap4j and while listening the incoming packets I send a packet. So I run the listening handler in a new thread:

```
ExecutorService pool;

Task task = new ListenerTask(); // Task implements Runnable
pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
pool.execute(task);
```

Then I send some packet and sleep:

```
.... //Send some packet

    try {
        LOGGER.log( Level.INFO, "Going to sleep" );
        Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
        LOGGER.log( Level.SEVERE, "Awakening" );
        Pool.shutdownNow();        
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But when sleeping during this 10 sec the new thread where the task listening for incoming packet is executing also stopped.

Output:

```
[pool-2-thread-1] o.p.c.PcapHandle                      : Starting loop.
[qtp238157928-40] d.p.u.TalkPcapHandler                 : Going to sleep
[qtp238157928-40] d.p.u.TalkPcapHandler                 : Awakening
[pool-2-thread-1] o.p.p.f.PacketFactories               : Succeeded in FactoryBinder.getInstance()
[pool-2-thread-1] d.p.u.TalkDiscoverPacketListener      : got Ethernet packet
```

During this 10 seconds the main thread (a RestController Spring component) is sleeping no packets are processed by the listening task. If remove the sleep instruction then the Rest Controller return a response and the incoming packet listener keep running. So it seems than the listening task is running in a new thread, but when sleeping the current thread it makes the other thread to be suspended also.

Comment: why are the messages `"Going to sleep"` and `"Awakening"` going from the different sources `d.p.u.TalkPcapHandler ` and `d.p.u.POFTalkPcapHandler` if they are written in the same place?

Comment: I am sorry I edited the output, they are called from same place, I changed the POFTalk references by Talk I edited now again. It seems now that the problem is the listener is running in a new thread but not ready yet when the packet is sent, so I need to check some precondition before sending the packet

Comment: it's unclear to me where these snippets are being executed, could you wrap them in methods and classes to allow us to see a full picture?

Comment: Well what it seems after some test I made is the listener is executing in a new thread, but the pcap4j get the packets not when they arrive but when some buffer is full or some timeout is reached. So my issue is a pcap4j issue and not a thread issue. I would also edit my question wrapping the snipped in methods and classes as you sugest.

Comment: Now my issue is solved by changing  the Listener implementation and using 0 value for the timeout parameter  nif.openLive(65536, PromiscuousMode.PROMISCUOUS, 0);